# Check if element is clicked or hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible in jQuery to know if an element is clicked or hasClass()

This is what I've tried without success

```
if($('.subCat span[data-value="all"]').hasClass('checked') || $('.subCat span[data-value="all"]').click()){
        alert('woohoo');
    }
```

So how can I achieve this? I need to script to be executed when clicked or if it has the required class.

Thanks

Comment: And on what event do you want to check this?

Comment: The click check seems easy but I'm confused by the hasClass part. Do you have other code that is modifying the class of the `.subCat span[data-value="all"]` element(s)?

Comment: _"Check if element is clicked"_ - Do you mean you want to do something immediately in response when the user clicks said element, or you want to be able to test later whether the element has been clicked at some stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a click event, not an if statement.

```
$('.subCat').on("click", 'span[data-value="all"].checked', function(){
    alert("woohoo foobar");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To tell if it is clicked, you need to add an event handler

```
$(document).on("click",'.subCat span[data-value="all"]', function(){
    alert("I was clicked");
});
```

There are no events to tell you if it was a required class. If you want to check when the page is loaded, you can do it than.

```
$( function() {
    $('.subCat span[data-value="all"]').filter('.checked').each( function(){
        alert("I have a checked class at ready");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the function to run on click as well as initially for the elements with the checked class, I would suggest this:

```
function doStuff() {
    alert('woohoo');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will wire up a click event. When the matching elements are clicked,
    // the doStuff function will run.
    $('.subCat span[data-value="all"]').click(doStuff);

    // This will call the doStuff function for every matched element on the
    // document ready.
    $.each($('.subCat span[data-value="all"].checked'), function(index, value) {
        doStuff();
    });
});
```